# CSS3: max-width & min-width

Tags: css

When i am taking `min-width:368px;` in desktop mode it is working but after that  as  i am using media queries and i am converting it to `max-width:368px` (for mobile and tablet) and  it is not working.It is taking `min-width` value not `max-width` value. Why?.

Example:

```
min-width: 368px;(desktop );
max-width: 368px;(mobile, tablet);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait){
 /* some CSS here */
}

/* #### Mobile Phones Landscape #### */
 @media screen and (max-device-width: 640px) and (orientation:landscape){
 /* some CSS here */
 }

/* #### Mobile Phones Portrait or Landscape #### */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px){
 /* some CSS here */
}

/* #### iPhone 4+ Portrait or Landscape #### */
@media screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
 /* some CSS here */
}

 /* #### iPhone 5 Portrait or Landscape #### */
 @media (device-height: 568px) and (device-width: 320px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
 /* some CSS here */
}

 /* #### iPhone 6 and 6 plus Portrait or Landscape #### */
  @media (min-device-height: 667px) and (min-device-width: 375px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
  /* some CSS here */
  }

   /* #### Tablets Portrait or Landscape #### */
   @media screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px){
   /* some CSS here */
}

 /* #### Desktops #### */
 @media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
  /* some CSS here */
}
```